# typescript react redux and redux-thunk using actionType as property in child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I have an example of two components Tasks and Task
in parent component **Tasks** I have connected store

```
type Props = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>
const mapDispatchToProps = { updateTask };
const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
export default connector(Tasks)
```

then in child **Task** I want to use updateTask as I don't want to have connected each task to redux

Task looks like

```
type Props = {
  updateTask: typeof updateTask
}
```

but that code leads to

> Type '(taskId: string, updatedTask: Partial) => void' is not assignable to type '(taskId: string, updatedTask: Partial) => ThunkAction'.   Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ThunkAction'.

of course, as it does not go via redux connect

so my question is it's safe to use `InferThunkActionCreatorType` from 'react-redux' library?

```
type Props = {
  updateTask: InferThunkActionCreatorType<typeof updateTaskAndPropagate>
}
```

definition is

```
export type InferThunkActionCreatorType<TActionCreator extends (...args: any[]) => any> =
    TActionCreator extends (...args: infer TParams) => (...args: any[]) => infer TReturn
        ? (...args: TParams) => TReturn
        : TActionCreator;
```

it's exactly what I need same function parameters but the return type is void

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's the perfect type for your use case. 
It is what is being used in the `Connect` type (the signature of the connect function), so it mimics exactly what you are looking for.

So you'd do

```
type Props = {
  updateTask: InferThunkActionCreatorType<typeof updateTask>
}
```

Oh, just in case you weren't aware: there is a `ConnectedProps` type now that will make it easier for you to type `connect`: [documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/static-typing#inferring-the-connected-props-automatically)

Might generally come in handy :)

Comment: yeah check first line in code section :) already using it
```type Props = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>```

Comment: Whoops, missed that one :D

Comment: but thanks for confirmation! :) now it's perfectly typesafe! :)